# Add Content Security Policy for inline event handlers

Tags: javascript, content-security-policy

I want to relax CSP for jquery.inputmask.min.js for inline event handlers used in my project.
For which I have to add 'unsafe-hashed-attributes' in 'script-src' and hash of jquery.inputmask.min.js.
Problem is Chrome is not giving me hash of this file in concole when it give CSP error.
I got hash of file from https://report-uri.com/home/hash and included in CSP but still chrome is refusing to execute inline event handlers in this file.

This is the error I get when remove unsafe-inline
[This error should give me hash of the script instead it gives ('sha256-...')](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8eqV.png)

I want to allow execution of inline event handlers without using 'unsafe-inline' as it is very unsafe.

Comment: `unsafe-hashed-attributes` hasn’t been implemented in Chrome yet, right? See https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=771922

Comment: Those inline event handlers aren’t coming from the used jQuery plugin, but from your own code, I assume? Then it would make more sense to fix it there, no?

Comment: Thanks for reply.

I think inline event handlers are coming from JQuery plugin which can be seen in this screen shot https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8eqV.png

Is there any way to allow inline event handlers to execute with safe CSP in chrome without using 'unsafe-line'? Because CSP evaluator shows unsafe-line as very unsafe.

Comment: No, there’s no way to specify a policy that allows inline event handlers without specifying 'unsafe-inline'. Any inline JavaScript code carries a risk — there’s nothing special about inline event handlers that somehow makes them less risky or more safe. If you want to mitigate that risk, then you have the choice to not use third-party code that injects inline event handlers. But if you instead choose to use that third-party code, then your choice instead is pretty much to just to not use CSP (because if you find yourself needing to use 'unsafe-inline', you might as well not be using CSP at all